# How can I do this Get on volley?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I have the following **URL: http://localhost:3000/api/bodega/list?valor=Bodega GENERAL** , 
when testing it using postman it works correctly and brings me the data. But now I'm trying to do it using volley with the following code

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String Ruta = null;


        //URL para realizar la peticion
        Ruta = V_URL_MON + "/api/bodega/list?valor=" + "Bodega GENERAL";

            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Ruta, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    recuperarID = jsonObject.getString("_id");
                                }
                                catch(JSONException e) {

                                }
                            }

                            Variables_Globales.BODEGA_ORIGEN = recuperarID;

                        }
                    } ,
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            Toast.makeText(Crear_Traslado.this, "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            queue.add(request);
```

It is generating an error Unable to fetch data: null, doing tests I realized that the error is caused by the URL "/api/bodega/list?valor=" + "Bodega GENERAL", specifically in "Bodega GENERAL", because if I remove the space it works correctly

Comment: Your formatting looks broken, maybe try using back ticks to code-font the URL? (back tick is the character under the tilde on US keyboards, a single left quote.)

Comment: Also, isn't localhost going to be a different computer on your development device vs whatever is running Postman?

Comment: That is the solution **URLEncoder.encode(Variables_Globales.BODEGA_ORIGEN);**